# Why is this condition being met when verifying parameters using the -notMatch condition?

Tags: azure, powershell, testing, azure-pipelines, assertion

I am validating parameters passed into a release pipeline with Powershell. The parameter I am passing as a pipeline variable is `val1`. Here is my code below:

```
if ("$(Value)" -notMatch "val1" -or "$(Value)" -notMatch "val2"){
  Write-Host "$(Value) must be val1 || val2"
  Write-Host "Value of param: "$(Value)""
  exit 1
}
```

When I print my value is states `val1`. Why is this condition being met? I thought perhaps it was because its case sensitive however even when I modify the condition to catch the exact case, it's still being met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
if ("$(Value)" -notMatch "val1" -and "$(Value)" -notMatch "val2"){
  Write-Host "$(Value) must be val1 || val2"
  Write-Host "Value of param: "$(Value)""
  exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your variable should have only `val1` or `val2`, you have to use `-and` instead `-or`.

```
if ("$(Value)" -notMatch "val1" -and "$(Value)" -notMatch "val2"){
  Write-Host "$(Value) must be val1 || val2"
  Write-Host "Value of param: "$(Value)""
  exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Note: `$(Value)` in the question as well as in the code below is an *Azure pipeline macro*, not a *PowerShell variable reference* such as `$Value`. Since such a macro is expanded to its value *before* PowerShell sees it, enclosing it in `"..."` - again, as in the question and in the code below - ensures that no syntax error occurs if the value happens to contain spaces or other PowerShell metacharacters.</sup>

The [Shamrai Aleksander's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66318113/45375) explains the logic error, but there may be an additional problem:

- **`-match`** (and its `-notmatch` variant), the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match), **matches *substrings* by default**, so that `"$(Value)"` expanding to `aval1`, for instance, would mistakenly pass the test as well.
- for ***literal*, *whole-value* comparisons against a *collection***, you can use the **[`-in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in) operator** (note that `-contains` serves the same purpose only with the operands reversed) and its variants, notably `-notin` in this case; use `-cnotin` for case-*sensitive* comparisons.

```
# Note: `$(Value)` is an *Azure pipeline macro (variable)*, which is expanded
#       *before* PowerShell sees the code.
#       In pure PowerShell code, the equivalent would be just `$Value`
if ("$(Value)" -notin 'val1', 'val2') {
  Write-Error '$(Value) must be val1 || val2'
  exit 1
}
```

---

> I thought perhaps it was because its case-sensitive however

Note that ***all* PowerShell operators are case-*insensitive* by default** (when they operate on text); PowerShell is case-insensitive by default in most respects.

Case-*sensitive* operation requires use of the `c` prefixed *variants*, such as `-cmatch`.

Optionally, to signal the intent more clearly, you can signal case-*insensitive* operation by using the `i`-prefixed variants, such as `-imatch` (all `i`-prefixed variants behave like their non-prefixed base forms).